# Nutch in Hadoop 2.x

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cluster-computing, nutch

I have a three-node cluster running Hadoop 2.2.0 and HBase 0.98.1 and I need to use a Nutch 2.2.1 crawler on top of that. But it only supports Hadoop versions from 1.x branch. By now I am able to submit a Nutch job to my cluster, but it fails with java.lang.NumberFormatException.
So my question is pretty simple: how do I make Nutch work in my environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment it's impossible to integrate Nutch 2.2.1 (Gora 0.3) with HBase 0.98.x.
See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GORA-304

Official Nutch tutorial recommends only 0.90.x HBase branch:
http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial

Also you can download HBase 0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0 version which I created and tested today:
https://github.com/dobromyslov/hbase/releases/tag/0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0

Take a note that Nutch 2.2.1 does not support HBase 0.94.x and you have to get the latest Nutch 2.x from Git branch: https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/2.x

Comment: Yesterday tested Apache Nutch 2.x (from Git repo 2.x branch) with the mentioned Apache HBase 0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0 and with Apache Hadoop 2.5.0. Works rather well. Fetched and parsed a couple of sites with Nutch 2.x without any troubles. Now trying to write custom parser plugins. It's not easy because only a small part of docs from Nutch 1.x fits 2.x. So I have to look through the sources and API docs.